# SQL Server 2019 installation microsoft odbc driver 17 download error

Tags: sql-server, installation, odbc

So I've been spending quite some time now to fix this issue.

While installing SQL Server 2019 I have this error: [image: Download error]

I already filled in the downloaded file for Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 from here :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

When I click 'OK' I get the following error:

[image]

Honestly I am completely clueless what to do.
Been spending the entire day just to get a local database running..
Any ideas?
What info do you need?

- Installation of SQL Server 2019
- Windows 10 v 10.0.17763 Build 17763

Comment: did you get past this issue, if so, can you post the solution please? I have the same problem now... thanks

Comment: for anyone else who stumbles on this thread, the solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400454/sql-server-2019-express-installation-failed-because-it-could-not-find-the-2017-d

Answer (score 15):

In my case, Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server was already installed, but SQL Server 2019 install said it could not find it. The resolution was to Uninstall Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, and let ISO install it's own.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: This should be the only answer to all these problems.