# SQL Server 2019 Express installation failed because it could not find the 2017 driver?

Tags: sql-server

I installed the basic configuration of SQL Server 2019 and got an error at the end:

> Oops
>
> Unable to install SQL Server (setup.exe).
>
> Exit code (Decimal): -2068052310
>
> Error description: An installation package for the product Microsoft
> ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server cannot be found. Try the installation
> again using a valid copy of the installation package 'msodbcsql.msi'.

I have the log file if this is helpful. I'm mystified why it's looking for this driver.

OS: Windows 10 Home

Comment: A two-second Google search for *msodbcsql.msi* turns up this Microsoft [downloadl page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567)

Comment: The application won't recognize it. I have the 2017 installer but 2019 installation won't "find" it.

Comment: The first step is to try using "Run as administrator" to install it. After that, you will need to look in the installation logs (which may poiint to other logs) to find the exact version of whatever it is that isn't installing/uninstalling, and then do a search for the version number.

Comment: *"I'm mystified why it's looking for this driver."* Because v17 is (at the time of writing) the most current version of the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. It's the same ODBC driver for multiple versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 7):

Have you already install SQL Server on this computer? If yes - try uninstall this driver, and then install SQL Server again.

Comment: This also worked for me, but was caused by aborting an initial installation of SQL Server express 2019. Subsequent attempts then complained about the missing .msi in the `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` folder.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, just download the package [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567) and then run again the SQL Express installer.

Comment: During interactive install the installer asked for the path to msodbcsql_[version]_x64.msi, but wasn't satisfied with the linked/downloaded MSI. The path supplied by the installer seemed to indicate the package was once installed from automatic software deployment, which had probably failed. Installing the linked msodbcsql.msi manually first solved the problem during SQL Server 2019 installation.

Comment: The link provided is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2):

I remove the setup of the SQL server application and my ODBC driver
then I setup:
SQL server 2019
and SSMS:SQL server management system

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked, after I deleted the folder that it created at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server
```

Then I reran the installation file.

Answer (score 0):

Open the **Windows Powershell** as administrator and execute this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type Dword

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type Dword
```

Answer (score 0):

You must uninstall odbc driver from program and features so try again.
I do it and install it

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just needed to uninstall the ODBC driver from Control Panel, and it worked.