# "Microsoft OBDC Driver 17 for SQL Server - The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable" Installing MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have tried numerous times to install Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Express Edition. I get very close, then I see an error (see images). Is this simply a matter of installing the msoledsql driver? [enter image description here]

[image: 1]

In a previous install attempt, I think the message was to download msodbcsql.msi, which I did, and which didn't work.

What are your insights on this?

Comment: There's a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400454/sql-server-2019-express-installation-failed-because-it-could-not-find-the-2017-d, and also this link may help you out as it steps through what that person did to troubleshoot and ultimately resolve https://sqlquantumleap.com/2019/05/05/error-2068643839-1602-installing-msoledbsql-msi-and-msodbcsql-msi-for-sql-server-2019-ctp-2-5/

Comment: Thanks, Craig. I had seen that comment prior to posting this question. I'm still having trouble, but this install is not mission-critical. I can take antoher approach. Thanks again for your response.